# PayPal - Migrating from OpenID to OAuth

Tags: paypal, oauth, openid

Using OpenID, PayPal returns the user's id in "openid.identity" field in format: https://www.paypal.com/webapps/auth/user/OPENID_ID
While using the same PayPal account using OAuth2.0 PayPal returns the user's id in "user_id" field in different format (and value): https://www.paypal.com/webapps/auth/identity/user/OAUTH_ID

How can I identify an existing user in my database?
I didn't found any migration plan.

Thanks